# Mathematical induction (theory)

Tags: proof-verification

I've got a question about mathematical induction.

$\bigg(P(0) \land \big[\forall n\in \mathbb{N},\;\; P(n)\implies P(n+1)\big]\bigg)\implies \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \; P(n)$

for the inductive step usually we say

***"Let any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and we assume that $P(n)$ holds and we will show that P(n+1) holds"***

But today I have seen this on an **another forum**

***"We assume there exists $n$ such that $P(n)$ holds..."***

I told them that is formally wrong, because we will prove that $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ only for a specific $n$

What is your point of view, Am I right?

---

Example we want to prove that $\forall n\ge 1, \quad 2^n>n$

Induction step ($\forall n\ge 1,\;\; P(n)\implies P(n+1)$)

**(*) Let any $n\ge 1$ and we assume that $2^n>n$ holds**

$2^{n+1}>n+1\iff 2^n+2^n>n+1$ as $2^n>n$ and $2^n>1$, we conclude that$2^{n+1}>n+1$ holds

So we have proved that $\forall n\ge 1,\;\; P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ which means $\forall n\ge 1,\;\; P(1)\implies P(2)\implies \cdots \implies P(n)\implies P(n+1)\cdots$

It remains the **base step** because we know noting about $P(1)$, $P(2)$ and ...

$P(1) :2^1>1$ so $P(1)$ is true

So we can conclude that $\forall n\ge 1, \quad 2^n>n$

---

If somone says for the induction step **(*)**

***"We assume *there exists* $n\ge 1$ such that $2^n>n$ holds..."***

this "there exists" annoys me

Comment: If you make no special assumption on $n$, then you actually proved that “if $P(n)$ then $P(n+1)$” is true for every $n$. It's just a sloppy way to say “let $n$ be any natural number”.

Comment: my question is, if someone says for the induction step "We assume there exists n such that P(n) holds and we will show that P(n+1) holds"  is it wrong or not please? that is my question

Comment: It's a sloppy way to express the usage of induction. Better not using it. I guess you can reformulate that proof in a more rigorous language.

Comment: so that is wrong, thanks

Comment: yes it's what I told them, that is formally wrong to say that!!

Comment: Only one more question, why the "there exists n\ge 1" annoy you? It is just the induction hypotesis, how would you reformulate that?

Comment: Let any $n\ge 1$, and we assume $P(n)$ holds

Comment: to prove $\forall n$, you take an unspecified $n$ then we assume that $P(n)$ holds and we show $P(n+1)$ from $P(n)$, if it works for an unspecified $n$ it works for all $n$

Comment: if you say we assume there exists n such that P(n), it means we assume $P(n)$ holds for specifics $n$ and not for any

Comment: so we can't conclude $\forall n\quad  P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ but $\exists n \quad  P(n)\implies P(n+1)$

Comment: @Stu The part $\exists n$ such that $P(n)$ holds is just the induction hypothesis (it suffices one value for n). From here by the induction step we show that $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ and of course that fact needs to be true for all $n\ge n_1$. Now, with reference to the base case $P(n_0)$, if $n_0\ge n_1$ we are done otherwise we need to prove the base case for some $n\ge n_1$.

Answer (score 1):

After the base case, that is $\exists n_0$ such that $P(n_0)$ holds, for the induction step we assume as *induction hypothesis* that for some $n$ $P(n)$ holds and we need to show that $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$.

Note that when we prove the induction step we need to check that $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ holds for $n\ge n_0$ otherwise we need to check again the base case.

For example when we prove by induction that $2^n\ge n^2$ we have that for the base case $n=0$ works but the induction step holds only for $n\ge 3$ then we need to prove the base case for $n\ge 3$ otherwise the proof by induction is wrong.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83764/discussion-on-answer-by-gimusi-mathematical-induction-theory).

Comment: @AloizioMacedo You are right sorry for that, even if our comments were completely inherent to the object raised by the OP. I would have deleted that after a while. Thanks