# How to prove this mathematical induction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

Can someone explain this prove mathematical induction question?

> Use mathematical induction to prove the following expression:
> $$
> \sum_{k = 1}^{n} 2^{n + 1} - 1.
> $$
> I tried my best to solve it but when i tried to prove for p(1) it got failed and for p(0) it is working fine.

I am new to mathematical induction and have test tomorrow.

I am new to this maths stack exchange and please for give if there is any formatting mistakes.

[Tried to solve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwY6H.jpg)

[Tried to solve this - Continued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVPMq.jpg)

Please help me out and thanks.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i= a_n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i$ for $n\ge1$ by the only way to rigorously define $\sum$

Comment: Maybe your problem is related to the fact that the given identity is wrong. Try with the correct version that is $\sum_{i=0}^n2^i=2^{n+1}-1$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the text, it should be

$$\sum_{i=0}^n2^i=2^{n+1}-1$$

then proceed firstly by base case and then by induction step assuming true $P(n)$ and deriving from it $P(n+1)$.

Refer also to the related

- [Mathematical induction (theory)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2933655/505767)
- [Proving $1^3+ 2^3 + \cdots + n^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ using induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62171/505767)

Comment: or it should be $\ldots =2^{n+1}-2$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Equivalentelly yes of course, but referring to the usual expression for the geometric series I think that the typo is likely to be that for $i=0$.

Comment: @gimusi Thanks for the answering the query. Can you please also clear the solution once ? I know i should do it myself but it has become very confusing now. Can you ?

Comment: @HimanshuChawla No I can't but I can give you a further tip. Start from $$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}2^i=2^{n+1}+\sum_{i=0}^n2^i=\ldots$$ and try to show that $$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}2^i=2^{n+2}-1$$ Also take a look to others induction proof you can find here on MSE and practice a lot on that.

Comment: @HimanshuChawla Refer for example to [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2933655/505767)

Comment: @gimusi I have just tried to solve the question on my own and got stucked at the last step. I hope now you can help me out. Attaching the images

Comment: Try to follow the hint I gave here two comments above. I’ll take a look to your work. To do that you should be confident with induction method. If you have doubts on that you could start proving simpler identity as for example $\sum_{i=1}^n i=n(n+1)/2$. Have you already proved that one?

Comment: @gimusi I have just edited and added one more step to my answer. Please check it once and just give me the hint or correct me up where i am wrong. I know i am at the very last step to get it proved.

Comment: The base case is ok and it suffices to prove P(1), I don’t understand what you are doing for the induction step, we need to consider the sum as shown here above.